# How to make Mobile Show the right keyboard and How to support auto complete in Forms?

Tags: html, mobile, webforms, keyboard

When We see a Form in Mobile , it shows right Keyboard for each field.for E-Mail , it shows a keyboard with @ sign and ".com" button. For Phone Number or any kind of number , it shows Numeric Keyboard.How to make a form like that ?
In other case , in forms and in any platform ,  when you going to enter an email address , it suggests you previously entered ones. What method handles it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , These methods are simply Available by Editing attributes **name** and **type** , you must just choose a correct a one.

**Mobile Keyboard Support:**

in any platform that uses physical keyboard , there's no difference between **text** and **email** and etc types of input. (However browsers make sure you enter a valid input even in PC right now)

so , if you want to make your form mobile-friendly , simply choose the right one.
Now you see this one:

```
<input type="text" />
```

is different with This one:

```
<input type="email" />
```

In any case require different keyboard , you should determine a correct type of input to have an standard form.
You can see possible arguments of type attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

**support auto complete or suggest**

For supporting suggestions in your input , you must use type and name attribute both to make the best experience , you must simply use common names. for E-mail : use **email** in name , For username : **username** and for name : name or **first_name**
Like that , your form will be friendly with mobile keyboard and suggestions